# Portfolio simulator

Tags: javascript, function, object, stock, portfolio

I am trying to program a basic version of a stock portfolio simulator. The initial starting cash is 100,000. The user should choose to buy from a few defined stocks at a fixed share price. Then be able to sell for a greater fixed price. How can I fix the current code so that I only sell the stocks that I have bought, and it automatically adjusts the portfolio value. I am new at programming so any criticism is welcomed.

```
    var portfolio = {
    intial: 100000,
    sharetotal: 0,

    add: function(sharePrice){
        this.sharetotal += (sharePrice||0);
    },

    buy: function(stock,quantity){
        switch (stock){
        case "Apple": this.add(0.98 * quantity); break;
        case "Google": this.add(1.23 * quantity); break;
        case "Yahoo": this.add(4.99 * quantity); break;
        case "3M": this.add(0.45 * quantity); break;
        }
        return true;
    },

    sell: function (stock,quantity){
    switch (stock){
        case "Apple": this.add(1.98 * quantity); break;
        case "Google": this.add(2.23 * quantity); break;
        case "Yahoo": this.add(3.99 * quantity); break;
        case "3M": this.add(4.45 * quantity); break;
        }
    }

};

portfolio.buy('Apple',10);
//portfolio.sell('Apple', 10);
var net = portfolio.intial+portfolio.sharetotal

console.log(net)
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on the code review site.

Answer (score 0):

You need some local storage in your portfolio class to store the stocks that you own. Something like an array of stock objects where each object has a name, shares and shareprice. The `add` function should add stocks to that storage, not just increment the value. You would then write a `value` function that adds up the values of the stocks in the stored stocks and returns that as the total value.